# How to implement Marquee effect on Collapsing toolbar and Toolbar in android

Tags: android, marquee, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I am working on an android application and I am using collapsing toolbar and Toolbar android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar in my application. Now When I show title on any page with collapsing toolbar and title is very long then it gives dot dot... when it is in expanded conditions and it is fine but when the title is collapsed and shown in the toolbar it should be shown with marquee effect, so that I can see the full title here.

Please help me if anyone know how to do this.

Thanks a lot in advanced :)